# MongoDB delete data using regex

Tags: pandas, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-atlas

I was able to use the following to delete data using pandas:

```
import re

repl = {r'<[^>]+>': '', 
        r'\r\n': ' ',
        r'Share to facebook|Share to twitter|Share to linkedin|Share on Facebook|Share on Twitter|Share on Messenger|Share on Whatsapp': ''}

articles['content'] = articles['content'].replace(repl, regex=True)
```

How can I do the same on the actual database thats in Atlas?

My data structure is:

```
_id:
title:
url:
description:
author:
publishedAt:
content:
source_id:
urlToImage:
summarization:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB does not have any built-in Operators to perform Regex Replace on the go (for now).

You can loop through the documents using the regex find in the programming language of your choice and replace that way instead.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import re


m_client = MongoClient("<MONGODB-URI-STRING")
db = m_client["<DB-NAME>"]
collection = db["<COLLECTION-NAME>"]

replace_dictionary = {
    r'<[^>]+>': '',
    r'\r\n': ' ',
    r'Share to facebook|Share to twitter|Share to linkedin|Share on Facebook|Share on Twitter|Share on Messenger|Share on Whatsapp': ''
}

count = 0

for it in collection.find({
    # Merge all refex finds to a single list
    "$or": [{"content": re.compile(x, re.IGNORECASE)} for x in replace_dictionary.keys()]
}, {
    # Project only the field to be replaced for faster execution of script
    "content": 1
}):
  #  Iterate over regex and replacements and apply the same using `re.sub` 
  for k, v in replace_dictionary.items():
    it["content"] = re.sub(
        pattern=k,
        repl=v,
        string=it["content"],
    )

  # Update the regex replaced string
  collection.update_one({
    "_id": it["_id"]
  }, {
    "$set": {
        "content": it['content']
    }
  })

  # Count to keep track of completion
  count += 1
  print("\r", count, end='')

print("DONE!!!")
```

Comment: I marked the answer as solved, but if i run the script a second time, it still "deletes" documents. I was expecting to get 0

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by delete. The script deletes nothing. It will only replace the regex matched text and update the `content` key, nothing more. Can you elaborate on the issue you are facing?